# How to make an app for the 4inch screen in xcode and not stretch it out

Tags: xcode

When I make my app for the 4inch screen i just stretch it out! I dont want to do that i want it to look the same when running on the iphone 4 and the 5.

Comment: You're going to need to expand on this question a *lot*. What do you mean by it's stretched out? What is your app using as it's views? Show us screenshots maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a portion of your image stretchable, for example, if you have a rounded corner background, you could stretch the centre of it without deforming the corners. Same goes for any other type of background (I assume you have a background that needs to be stretched). Once you decide what portion of it you want to deform, you can use UIImage's `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` to avoid stretching the rest.

If you're not ready to compromise and stretch a portion of your image, I'm afraid you'll have to use 2 different images, one for 4 inches (iPhone 5) and one for 3.5 inches (iPhone <5).